# How does the relationship compare between earthly children and spiritual children in LDS theology?

Tags: lds, afterlife, family

As I understand LDS teaching, a couple may have an eternal family with the children they produce here on earth.  However, that couple may also attain godhood and then produce spiritual children for their own worlds as well.  Thus, a couple may have both earthly children as well as celestial or spiritual children.  Their spiritual children then take on flesh on another world and seek to attain godhood themselves.  (This is the doctrine of eternal progression, as I understand it.)

So, my question concerns the relationship of the couple that attains godhood to their spiritual or celestial children and how that is similar or different from the relationship they have with the children they had here on earth.

Do the celestial or spiritual children become part of their eternal family as well?  Do spiritual children share equal status with earthly children?

Comment: "For their own planet" is a foreign concept to Mormons. Planets, in general, are not really well understood in Mormon doctrine, so maybe try to abstract your questions away from "planets."

Comment: @Matt Perhaps worlds?

Comment: That word is more common in LDS theology, so it's definitely better. Just realize that, in LDS scriptures ([Moses 1:35](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.35?lang=eng#34)), God gave even Moses only a vision of the inhabitants of this world, so most remarks on other worlds are mere speculation, not doctrine.

Comment: @Matt Yes, but I assumed that someone may have commented on this in the past 80 years and was hoping for references to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All people on Earth are spiritual sons and daughters of God, who is called Heavenly Father for this reason.  So, all those on this Earth who "attain godhood" will be reunited with Him in one giant happy eternal family.  This includes a couple and their earthly children.

At this point, it becomes more speculation on my part.  There may be references for what I am about to say, but I couldn't tell you them.

As I understand it, any spiritual children that a celestial couple has will go through the whole plan of salvation that we are currently going through on another "world".  As they attain godhood, they will be added into the big happy eternal family that will include their earthly parents, their spiritual parents, and our Heavenly Father and Mother.  As far as whether they will have "equal status" I would say yes in the sense that all people are equal in God's eye, but I would say no in the sense that the earthly children would have much much more time to progress, and therefore will be at a higher level similar to how God is at a higher level than us.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)